# Proof that P-Names allow the generation of all sets derivable from G in M[G]

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Kunen says about Forcing : The first step is to define M [G]. Roughly, this will be the set of all sets which can be constructed from G by applying set-theoretic processes definable
in M. **Each element of M[G] will have a name in M, which tells how it has been constructed from G.**

Then the names are defined as :

$ \tau$ is a P-name iff $\tau$ is a relation and :

$$\forall <\sigma , p> \in \tau \text{ } [ \sigma \text{ is a P-name} \land p \in P]$$

**So the question is :** How does a P-name tell **how it has been constructed from G**, in terms of expressions in the language of set theory? So what is the link between a P-name and all set theory expressions, for example :

{ r } $\cup$ G ; {r} $\cap$ G ; G - { r } ; P - G etc..

So is there a proof that **ALL** Set Theory expressions involving G are included in some P-name ?

Comment: A posteriori, since M[G] is a model of set theory.

Comment: The standard proof that $M[G]$ is a model of ZFC will include proofs essentially that it's closed under the set operations, and many of the proofs will even tell you how you construct such a name (recursively in the structure of the term).  Then, just finish up by observing that $G$ itself has a $P$-name $\{ \langle \check p, p \rangle \mid p \in P \}$, and every element $x \in M$ has a $P$-name $\check x$.

Comment: Remember that "set theory expressions" are just abbreviations for things in terms of $\in$ alone. So showing that Separation in particular holds in $M[G]$ is probably what you want.